# Put a QLineEdit() into a QTreeWidgetItem()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Is it possible to put a QLineEdit() into a QTreeWidgetItem() in order to modify the text of the QTreeWidgetItem ?

Here is my code

```
def addItemsToTree(self, parent, text, checkable=False, expanded=True):
    self.item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [text])
    if checkable:
        self.item.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
    else:
        self.item.setFlags(self.item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    self.item.setExpanded(expanded)
    min = QLineEdit()
    max = QLineEdit()
    self.addChildTree(self.item, self.column, "Min =", "Min =")
    self.addChildTree(self.item, self.column, "Max =", "Max =")
    return self.item

def addChildTree(self, parent, column, title, data):
    item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [title])
    item.setData(column, Qt.UserRole, data)
    return item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should suffice to set your item flags to include `ItemIsEditable`:

```
self.item.setFlags(self.item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

You can also configure the [EditTriggers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum) to start editing as you like, e.g. upon double-clicking an item:

```
treeView.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)
```

Double-clicking an item in your treewidget should now bring up an editor - which by default is simply a `QLineEdit`.